# Are allocator construct and destroy member functions allowed to throw exceptions from internal logic?

Tags: c++, allocator, exception-safety

I'm writing my own container that requires nothrow movable and copyable types. I thought I could simplify logic a bit when it comes to exception safety. But I noticed that `construct` and `destroy` member functions of allocators have no wording about when they can and can't throw exceptions.

I'm pretty sure I've read the wording before. Otherwise, even if my type is nothrow movable, `construct` can still throw an exception from user-provided allocator when, say, I resize the buffer to increase capacity. This requires complex rollback code to guarantee strong exception safety that I really wanted to skip.

Is there a wording that allows to only throw exceptions from calling ctor/dtor or are allocators always require complex machinery to maintain exception safety?

Answer (score 3):

The allocator members can throw. If the standard doesn't say they *can't* throw, then they can throw.

But in practice, why would they?

Especially for `std::allocator::construct` and `std::allocator::destroy`, which do nothing more than just invoke a constructor or destructor. But you should be using `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct` and `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy` anyway, and those do nothing more than call `Alloc::construct` / `Alloc::destroy` if that exists, and invoke a constructor/destructor otherwise.

In theory, a pathological allocator could throw in those members, but you should assume they don't. You can't defend against pathologically stupid types.

Comment: If the standard allows such pathological allocators, maybe the spec can be reworded to make such allocators non-conforming.

Comment: It doesn't seem worth doing to me. The `construct` functions can still throw in general because the constructors can throw. It seems like asking allocators to provide an accurate noexcept-specifier for the `construct` function would be more useful. If the allocator doesn't do anything itself that can throw, and the object's constructor is `noexcept`, then the `construct` function would be `noexcept` too.

Answer (score 0):

The omission they have made has a reason (or two). First, destructors can throw. Second, the standard wants to avoid undefined behavior in useful contexts. If they outright banned throwing `destroy` in allocators, then you could not have an allocator that does non-trivial work in the `destroy` function. Imagine in tests, you could use an allocator which tracks the allocation, deallocation, construction, and destruction of objects. In this case, `destroy` may throw, as there may be some container the allocator is referencing which is needed to store the data. However, a good developer should know that throwing in a destructor, or, in this case, the allocator's `destroy` method, will likely invalid the state of the whole program. So, you can use `destroy`, in almost all cases, as *if* it would not throw, and allow unhandled exceptions/termination if it does.